# which font is exactly used in this pdf document?

Tags: fonts, pdf

[image]

Hi, does anybody can help to recognize the font of this file.
Please pay attention to "g"s.
If it is typewritten, which font is nowadays similar to that in Office word?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a type written document to me!

Comment: Since it is scanned I think that it is a simple tt font.

Comment: Just use `\ttfamily` or if you want in some words only `\texttt{foo}`.

Comment: Since this is clearly a typewritten document (people more than 25 years old may have seen a typewriter), there's little chance to get an identical output. And there's no reason to, either. It's as ugly as possible: 40 years ago it was the only method available for publishing own material, now such ugliness can easily be dispensed with.

Comment: If you can buy a typewriter, you'll get the same aesthetics and appeal.

Comment: @egreg, surely some Word documents do look uglier than that.

Comment: This is the third (or forth) time I saw people vote to close a what-font question. Is it really sufficient (and necessary) to guid people to that post? In my opinion, askers do not really need to follow those steps and get the *exact* font name. They may want to emphasis some feature and find an alternative. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The book is

> Local Fields, by [J. W. S. Cassels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._W._S._Cassels), Cambridge University Press, 1986

as testified by [this preview](https://books.google.it/books?id=UY52SQnV9w4C&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=The%20advent%20of%20the%20computer%20has%20immeasurably%20enhanced%20the%20armoury&source=bl&ots=qvD77PLO0H&sig=lf9D0KVciDy2T3Sb4dh1EqqdkcI&hl=it&sa=X&ei=JW2iVfekK8K2sQHax5CwCA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Google Books (the yellow bits are due to the search engine)

[image]

[This is a sample from page 3](https://books.google.it/books?id=UY52SQnV9w4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

At the time some publishers didn't want to afford big expenses for typesetting books with a small readers' base such as mathematics: the cost for typesetting math was much higher than for normal books. Thus they often accepted typewritten texts that were simply photographed and printed in offset.

The font is something you can find in some old British typewriter. You get an approximation with the standard Computer Modern Typewriter font (not the peculiar “g”, I'm afraid). Several math departments had very skilled typists that were able to get good results despite the medium. Anyway, this is something I'd not even try reproducing: it's even uglier than the average word processor document

Comment: I can hardly believe that Cambridge University Press couldn't afford typesetting such a book in 1986.

Comment: @Joseph The reason was surely economical.

Comment: @Joseph According to an expert in the field, a math book in a specialized field could be expected to sell less than 3000 copies. With today's technologies, printing on demand is very economical and also book typesetting is much less expensive, so there's no reason for camera-ready any more. At those times many books were printed like that; consider that the subject is very specialized: the choice was between ugly printing or no publishing at all.